# Copy a TFS mapped solution directory on desktop to work offline

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

hello i want to make a copy of my TFS solution to avoid the control of source code.
i mean to have 2 same solutions, one on tfs and one other without tfs.
tried to copy mapped folder solution on my desktop and VS 2010 return a message everytime as
1. work temporarily offline
2. remove permanently the solution

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you are working on the 'copy' then you can remove the source control bindings safely. If you have picked the wrong one, use the source control window to roll back the change.